# Question on a functional analysis exercise.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

These days I am doing some independent study of functional analysis. While solving problems, I could not handle the following part of an exercise (exercise 13, chapter 1 of Rudin's Functional Analysis).

Let $C$ be the vector space of all complex continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Define $$d(f,g)=\int_0^1 \frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|}dx.$$

Let $(C,\sigma)$ be $C$ with the topology induced by this metric. Let $(C,\tau)$ be the topological vector space defined by the seminorms $$p_x(f)=|f(x)| \quad (0\le x \le 1).$$

Prove that every $\tau-$bounded set in $C$ is also $\sigma-$bounded and that the identity map 
$id:(C,\tau)\to (C,\sigma)$ therefore carries bounded sets into bounded sets.

*Because of the definition of our seminorm, a set $E$ is $\tau-$bounded if and only if for each $x\in [0,1]$ there exists $M_x \ge 0$ such that $p_x(f)=|f(x)| \le M_x$ for all $f\in E$.

To show that $E$ is $\sigma-$bounded, I tried to prove that for any $\delta>0$, $B(0,\delta)$ absorbs $E$, i.e. there exists $t>0$ such that $\frac{1}{t} E \subset B(0,\delta)$, but I am stuck here.

I would really appreciate it if you could give me some sketches or hints on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch: Define $b_E(x) := \sup\limits_{f \in E} \lvert f(x)\rvert$. $b_E$ is the supremum of continuous functions, hence it is lower semicontinuous, hence measurable.

Apply the dominated convergence theorem to $\frac1t b_E$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I mistakenly thought that the sup function might not be measurable! Thanks again.

Comment: how will you claim that your function $b_{E}(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ as we need it to be continuous to define the distance between $b_{E}$ and $0$.

Comment: @bunny It will in general not be continuous, only lower semicontinuous. That suffices, since we use $$\int_0^1 \frac{b_E(x)}{1 + b_E(x)}\,dx$$ as an upper bound for $\{d(f,0) : f \in E\}$, not as the distance of an element of $C$ from $0$.

Comment: yes and  thanks for the help. i was also thinking the same but yet want to reconfirm. Thanks once again